# Looping in parallel using For Loop in Python

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying some for loop code to be added to my configuration to my router and switch.I need to output the data same data that are included on my router and switch list.

I tried normal and nested for loop.

```
routers = ['r1', 'r2', 'r3']
switches = ['s1', 's2', 's3']

for r in routers:
    print(r)
    print(s)
```

and

```
for r in routers:
    for s in switches:
        print(r)
        print(s)
```

I expect the output to be:

```
r1
r2
s1
s2
```

but my output was:

```
r2
s1
r2
s2
```

Comment: *I expect* is what you need?

Comment: yes sir. the 'I expect'

Comment: For that, you can simply go with **[print(x) for x in routers+switches]** if you want them paired, then go with **for i in range(len(routers)): print(routers[i], switches[i], sep='\n')**

Comment: Hi Sir Seraph, Thanks very much! it worked. I didn't it can be done like that.

Comment: you dont need a nested loop. Just iterate one after the other.

Comment: Why should `r3` and `s3` be omitted from the output? What's "parallel" here? Sounds like you want two serial loops; another one over the switches after you have looped over and printed the routers.

Comment: Thanks for the replies sirs, I think I got the logic.